# How do I migrate a ubuntu server vmware virtual machine with a broken snapshot chain

Tags: vmware-tools

I currently have a ubuntu 8 server virtual machine running within vmware server 2.0 on centos  and need to migrate the virtual machine to a server running vmware vsphere essentials.  However, copying the files to the new server or using vmware converter fails due to a broken snapshot chain.

How do I migrate the virtual machine if there is a broken snapshot chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably less tiresome to build a new Ubuntu box on the vSphere machine and copy over the *data* of the broken Ubuntu VM to the new one. What is the old server running? Copying data will save you a lot of time trying to figure out how to rebuild the snapshot chain, when it's not even necessary...

Comment: It is running ruby/rails on apache passenger and mysql. My main concern is that it also replicates mysql offsite using stunnel and I really don't want to reconfigure.

Comment: In that case, I suppose you can dd the whole VM through nc to the a new VM on the vSphere box. Painful process, but will work.